# Conditional summation in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy 2d array (8000x7200). I want to count the number of cells having a value greater than a specified threshold. I tried to do this using a double loop, but it takes a lot of time.
Is there a way to perform this calculation quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is probably something like `np.count_nonzero(x > threshold)`, where `x` is your 2-d array.

As the name implies, `count_nonzero` counts the number of elements that aren't zero. By making use of the fact that `True` is 1-ish, you can use it to count the number of elements that are `True`.

Answer (score 4):

Assume your variables are defined as

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
a = np.random.rand(8000, 7200)
threshold = .5
```

Then use `sum`
*`(a > threshold)` is a boolean array indicating every instance of a cell being greater than some `threshold`.  Since boolean values are a sub-class of `int`, with `False` as zero and `True` as one, we can easily sum them up.  `numpy`s `sum` sums over the entire array by default.

```
(a > threshold).sum()
28798689
```

Comment: this is almost spot on 50%

Comment: @Ev.Kounis that's by nature of the example I chose.

Comment: I know but I am still amused by it xD

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked fine but it takes more time than `np.count_nonzero`